# ActiveMQ Artemis management console fails to load due to Jolokia endpoint timeout. No error logs. Where to start debugging?

Tags: activemq-artemis, hawtio, jolokia, artemiscloud

I am using the [`activemq-artemis-operator`](https://github.com/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-operator) to deploy an `activemq-artemis` cluster.

When port-forwarding to the management console the UI does not load consistently. More often there is one endpoint which times out and all the UI fails to load.

Having limited knowledge with the stack I don't know where to start to debug this.

The payload always seems to be this:

```json
{"type":"exec","mbean":"hawtio:type=security,area=jmx,name=ArtemisJMXSecurity","operation":"canInvoke(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)","arguments":["org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"amq-broker\"","THIS_CHANGES"]}
```

Also logging and in and out again yields different results after every login. Sometimes the `Artemis` doesn't even show up and images are missing.

Would really appreciate some help to debug if possible.

EDIT: Some more context.

login.config

```java
activemq {
  org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
    reload=true
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.user="artemis-users.properties"
    org.apache.activemq.jaas.properties.role="artemis-roles.properties";
};
```

log4j2.properties

```
# Log4J 2 configuration
# Monitor config file every X seconds for updates
monitorInterval = 5
rootLogger = INFO, console
logger.activemq.name=org.apache.activemq
logger.activemq.level=WARN
logger.jolokia.name=org.jolokia
logger.jolokia.level=DEBUG
logger.artemis_server.name=org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server
logger.artemis_server.level=WARN
logger.artemis_journal.name=org.apache.activemq.artemis.journal
logger.artemis_journal.level=WARN
logger.artemis_utils.name=org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils
logger.artemis_utils.level=WARN
logger.critical_analyzer.name=org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.critical
logger.critical_analyzer.level=WARN
# Audit loggers: to enable change levels from OFF to INFO
logger.audit_base = OFF, audit_log_file
logger.audit_base.name = org.apache.activemq.audit.base
logger.audit_base.additivity = false
logger.audit_resource = OFF, audit_log_file
logger.audit_resource.name = org.apache.activemq.audit.resource
logger.audit_resource.additivity = false
logger.audit_message = OFF, audit_log_file
logger.audit_message.name = org.apache.activemq.audit.message
logger.audit_message.additivity = false
# Jetty logger levels
logger.jetty.name=org.eclipse.jetty
logger.jetty.level=WARN
# Quorum related logger levels
logger.curator.name=org.apache.curator
logger.curator.level=WARN
logger.zookeeper.name=org.apache.zookeeper
logger.zookeeper.level=WARN
# Console appender
appender.console.type=Console
appender.console.name=console
appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern=%d %-5level [%logger] %msg%n
# Log file appender
appender.log_file.type = RollingFile
appender.log_file.name = log_file
appender.log_file.fileName = ${sys:artemis.instance}/log/artemis.log
appender.log_file.filePattern = ${sys:artemis.instance}/log/artemis.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
appender.log_file.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.log_file.layout.pattern = %d %-5level [%logger] %msg%n
appender.log_file.policies.type = Policies
appender.log_file.policies.cron.type = CronTriggeringPolicy
appender.log_file.policies.cron.schedule = 0 0 0 * * ?
appender.log_file.policies.cron.evaluateOnStartup = true
# Audit log file appender
appender.audit_log_file.type = RollingFile
appender.audit_log_file.name = audit_log_file
appender.audit_log_file.fileName = ${sys:artemis.instance}/log/audit.log
appender.audit_log_file.filePattern = ${sys:artemis.instance}/log/audit.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
appender.audit_log_file.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.audit_log_file.layout.pattern = %d [AUDIT](%t) %msg%n
appender.audit_log_file.policies.type = Policies
appender.audit_log_file.policies.cron.type = CronTriggeringPolicy
```

bootstrap.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema">
  <jaas-security domain="activemq"/>
  <server configuration="file:/home/jboss/amq-broker/etc/broker.xml"/>
  <web customizer="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ForwardedRequestCustomizer" path="web" rootRedirectLocation="console">
      <binding uri="http://0.0.0.0:8161">
          <app url="activemq-branding" war="activemq-branding.war"/>
          <app url="artemis-plugin" war="artemis-plugin.war"/>
          <app url="console" war="console.war"/>
          <app url="metrics" war="metrics.war"/>
      </binding>
  </web>
</broker>
```

And last, but not least:
[**artemis-cr.yaml**](https://gist.github.com/moritzschmitz-oviva/4cc3f52ac2406d06f94f71c7a03fb845)

Comment: Could you add your ActveMQArtemis CR to the question?

Comment: @DomenicoFrancescoBruscino Added it at the end. It is really long, so I added it as GitHub Gist. Edit: The image we use is just a proxy for the official image. The init image copies the bootstrap, login.config etc into the container.

Comment: Another note: I tried setting up the broker in a new environment and slowly adjusted the vanilla CR to our CR, while trying to access the console. Couldn't tell any difference really. So this could be related to all the services accessing the broker, couldn't it?

Comment: Your config and CR LGTM. I also tried your CR and it works as expected. In the past I have already got a similar issue accessing a console of a broker with a lot of of addresses and queues. The console downloads the full tree of the addresses and queue after logging in. Could you increase the memory size and execute `artemis queue stat` if you still get the same issue?

Comment: @DomenicoFrancescoBruscino I increased CPU to 4 cores and memory to 4 Gi. `artemis queue stat` outputs ~280 queues. It is not working very reliable. Sometimes the console loads, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: In your CR I see `console.expose=false`, how are you accessing the console?

Comment: Using `kubectl port-forward svc/artemis-broker-hdls-svc 8161:8161`.

Comment: We moved back to a single instance broker for now, but have the same problem by the way.

Comment: Here is a minimal setup (works with `kind` for example) to reproduce the issue: https://gist.github.com/moritzschmitz-oviva/eaeec3b143e050b3da23131a3b82ce73. Once the broker is up, open a shell and execute: `/scripts/create-queues.sh`. After command is finished, port-forward to the console. Should work first time, but after some refreshing of the page the console will not load anymore.

Comment: Opened a ticket now: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-4482.

Comment: Your reproducer is great, I'm able to reproduce the issue. The cause of the issue seems the command `kubectl port-forward` indeed after getting the issue with `kubectl port-forward artemis-0 8161:8161` it still works with `kubectl port-forward artemis-0 8162:8161`